# Setting up Droid for development

Tags: android

I am trying to follow the instructions on this page "[Developing on a device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)". After I finished all the steps, and executes command "adb devices", my Droid is not listed. Is there anything else that I need to do if my device is Droid? It seems there are discussions on this issue but I could not find any definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the Droid is anything like my HTC Hero, you have to enable USB debugging on your device. It's somewhere hidden in your settings.

Edit: if you have followed the link you gave you probably already did so. What platform are you using. Windows, Linux, OSX?

Comment: My platform is windows xp. I did enable usb debugging on my device.
When usb is connected, "android composite adb interface" is detected as well as "usb mass storage device".

Comment: I assume you also installed the usb driver that came with the Android SDK?

Comment: I installed usb driver package revision 3 using Android SDK and AVD manager. When Droid is connected, device manager shows Android Phone -> Android Composite ADB Interface.

Comment: It is suddenly working now after turning the computer on and off a few times. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Good luck with your Android development :)